# How to add Canonical Tag to single page application in react js?

Tags: reactjs, seo

I have an eCommerce single page application in react js, I want to add **Canonical Tag** to make the **SEO** of my application better, but if I add `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />` it to my `index.html` that would apply on all pages.

- I'm I understanding that right?
- I have a `product page` for each product that's multi hundreds of pages, how can I add to those a Canonical Tag?

I would appreciate the help, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet-async) to change the canonical tag.  Use it within any component that renders on a route change.  Example:

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
<Helmet>
    <title>{pageTitle}</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href={pageURL} />
</Helmet>
```